# Normal distribution (Bell) curve for histogram in d3.js v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have made a Histogram in d3.js **v5** and I need help adding a normal distribution curve to it. Below is a code snippet. The full minimum reproducible example code if further below.

```
const data = [
  {"sizeBand": "0-45", "units": 56659},
  {"sizeBand": "46-65", "units": 137201},
  {"sizeBand": "66-85", "units": 201630},
  {"sizeBand": "85+", "units": 21939}
  ]    
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()        
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.units)])
      .range([graphHeight, 0]);

    const x = d3.scaleBand()
      .domain(data.map(item => item.sizeBand))
      .range([0, graphWidth])
      .paddingInner(0.2)
      .paddingOuter(0.2);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)    
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)

    xAxisGroup.call(xAxis)
    yAxisGroup.call(yAxis)

    rect1.data(data)
      .enter().append('rect')
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth)
      .attr('height', (d, i) => graphHeight - y(d.units))
      .attr('x', (d, i) => x(d.sizeBand))
      .attr('y', d => y(d.units))
```

Here is the full working [Histogram Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/lucasj01uk/amugos4y/12/) example.
Below is a sample image of what I'm looking for.

[image: Example Picture]

I have tried reproducing and deconstructing other examples like [this](https://gist.github.com/jsrubin/1fe23a1c6e287dcdc104c46f377b0235) but without success. The key things are for it to work in D3.JS v5 and it needs to work with the tooltip which in the linked js fiddle above.

Help will be greatly appreciated.